# QGIS Query Builder button greyed out

Tags: qgis-3, query

I want to query features under [Layer Properties] -> [Source] -> [Query Builder] but the query builder button is greyed out. The layer I'm using is from a shapefile with multiple demographic fields by US county. I'm using QGIS 3.16.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Please post your solution as answer (you can answer at your own questions) (you can even delete your question but maybe it helps other people).

Answer (score 1):

I must have made an error while familiarizing myself with QGIS. I removed the layer then re-added it and I'm able to Query it's features now.